# Print For-Loop results in a table

Tags: javascript, pentaho, kettle

I have *10* rows of data on my input step, i transform them in a **for-loop** and i should get more than *10* rows, but in this case i get the last transform of each iteration that the loop have for each data

I tried to use `appendToFile()` but the result data is not useful and pentaho read it as a unique header
On my `alert()` method i can see that the for loop transform the data.

```
var PERIODO = 2
var i
var fecha_final
//var ruta_acess ="D:\TEST.accdb"
//var contenido
////var contenido2
//var arreglo_completo
for (i=0; i<=PERIODO; i++){

fecha_final = dateAdd(FECHA_INICIO,"d",i)
Alert(i)
}
```

As I show in the below photo i get only *10* records and in the other photo appears the result that i want that are the results data of each iteration of the for-loop

**Modified JavaScript value photo:**

[image: Modified JavaScript value photo]

**Expected result:**

[image: Expected result]

**Obtained result:**

[image: Obtained result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For loops are not really a thing in PDI. Transformations work on sets of rows that flow through the steps, so it's best for performance and stability to use that mindset.

In your scenario each incoming row should end up as three copies, but with different calculated values based on a single new field (with values 0,1,2).

The way to do this in PDI is with a **Join rows (cartesian product)** step. It takes two sets of input rows and outputs a row for every combination of input rows, possibly filtered by defining a key field that has to match. So if you have 10 rows in the main input and 3 rows in the second, it will output 30 rows.

You will first need to create a data grid as the second input. Define a single integer field, name it something clear and on the second tab fill three rows with 0, 1 and 2 respectively.

Connect both inputs to the Join rows step. You don't need to configure any matching key.
The output of the Join step will be three rows for each input row, one with each of the values 0, 1, 2. Connect that output to a Calculator step and use the calculation Date A + B days to replace the logic from your javascript step.

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer, im new at pentaho and his features. Actually i complete my project using only javascript step but like i see it has more than just JS, and like you say is best when we talk about performance and stability. i will try to recreate why i did but using more features of pentaho. thanks again !

Comment: ...... by the way .. recently you create a sequence... i have diferent start - end dates and each one has a period of 12 months, 6 month or 1 month ... i know there is a way to make a condition and create the secuence according the perior of this dates ... if you have time i would like to know, but meanwhile i will see how i can do it.

Answer (score 0):

what i mean is that in the obtained result photo the "i" variable only shows the value of "3" and i would like to have "1", "2" and "3"

Answer (score 0):

to solve this i used

> var row = createRowCopy(getOutputRowMeta().size())
>   var idx = getInputRowMeta().size() 
>   row[idx++] = DPROCESS

this add a row for each result of the iteration.
before the tranformation result showed to me only the last value of each loop.

Comment: you can use **Clone Row** step, set a field for *Clone number*, and then use **Calculator** step (*Date A + B Months*) to set the corresponding date.